# Providing php generated xml file to javascript parser

Tags: javascript, php, xml, samsung-smart-tv

I am developing a smart tv app that plays live streams. App itself works fine, when i provide a valid xml playlist to it.

But when i use php to generate xml file (wich also generates fine), it doesnt work.

I get an error:

> TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this.XHRObj.responseXML.documentElement')

Here is my php file that generates videoList.xml, it works 100%.
In short words, this script checks if MAC address in database, and if it is, then it writes videoList.xml with walid live streaming links.
**SamsungAPI.php**

```
<?php
$MAC = $_GET['MAC'];
require_once('../config.php'); 
//Remove brackets form array
$_INFO = preg_replace('/[{}]/', '', $_INFO);
$mysqli = new mysqli($_INFO['host'], $_INFO['db_user'], $_INFO['db_pass'], $_INFO['db_name']);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE admin_notes = '$MAC' ";
$rs=$mysqli->query($sql);
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($rs);
if ($rows == 1) {
    //MAC FOUND
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    $file = "videoList.xml";
         $txt_file = file_get_contents('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/get.php?type=starlivev3&username=' . $username . '&password=' . $password . '&output=hls');
           $rows        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
              if(empty($rows[count($rows)-1])) {
                 unset($rows[count($rows)-1]);
                 $rows=array_map('trim',$rows);
              }
       $handle = fopen($file, "w+") or die('Could not open file');
       fwrite($handle, "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"."\n");
       fwrite($handle, "<rss version=\"2.0\">"."\n");
       fwrite($handle, "<channel>"."\n");
  foreach($rows as $row => $data)
       {
    //get row data
    $row_data = explode(',', $data);
    //replace _ with spaces
    $row_data[0] = str_replace('_', ' ', $row_data[0]);


       //generate playlist content
       fwrite($handle, "<item>"."\n");
       fwrite($handle, "<title>{$row_data[0]}</title>"."\n");
       fwrite($handle, "<link>{$row_data[1]}</link>"."\n");
       fwrite($handle, "<description> Reserved for EPG </description>"."\n");
       fwrite($handle, "</item>"."\n");
     }
fwrite($handle, "</channel>"."\n");
fwrite($handle, "</rss>");
fclose($handle);
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;

} else {
//MAC NOT FOUND
echo "MAC NOT FOUND";
}
mysqli_close($mysqli); // Closing Connection

?>
```

Then in samsung smart tv videoplayer app, i have xml parser like this:

**Server.js**

```
var Server =
{
    /* Callback function to be set by client */
    dataReceivedCallback : null,

    XHRObj : null,
    url : "http://myvalidhost.com/samsungAPI.php?MAC=02000027000b"
}

Server.init = function()
{
    var success = true;

    if (this.XHRObj)
    {
        this.XHRObj.destroy();  // Save memory
        this.XHRObj = null;
    }

    return success;
}

Server.fetchVideoList = function()
{
    if (this.XHRObj == null)
    {
        this.XHRObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    if (this.XHRObj)
    {
        this.XHRObj.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (Server.XHRObj.readyState == 4)
                {
                    Server.createVideoList();
                }
            }

        this.XHRObj.open("GET", this.url, true);
        this.XHRObj.send(null);
     }
    else
    {
        alert("Failed to create XHR");
    }
}

Server.createVideoList = function()
{
    if (this.XHRObj.status != 200)
    {
        Display.status("XML Server Error " + this.XHRObj.status);
    }
    else
    {
        var xmlElement = this.XHRObj.responseXML.documentElement;

        if (!xmlElement)
        {
            alert("Failed to get valid XML");
        }
        else
        {
            // Parse RSS
            // Get all "item" elements
            var items = xmlElement.getElementsByTagName("item");

            var videoNames = [ ];
            var videoURLs = [ ];
            var videoDescriptions = [ ];

            for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++)
            {
                var titleElement = items[index].getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
                var descriptionElement = items[index].getElementsByTagName("description")[0];
                var linkElement = items[index].getElementsByTagName("link")[0];
                if (titleElement && descriptionElement && linkElement)
                {
                    videoNames[index] = titleElement.firstChild.data;

                    if(linkElement.firstChild.data.substring(0,4) !="http"){
                        alert("asdasdasd  "+linkElement.firstChild.data.substring(0,4));
                        var rootPath = window.location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                        var Abs_path = unescape(rootPath).split("file://")[1]+linkElement.firstChild.data;
                        videoURLs[index] = Abs_path;        
                    }
                    else{
                        videoURLs[index] = linkElement.firstChild.data;                         
                    }
                    videoDescriptions[index] = descriptionElement.firstChild.data;
                }
            }

            Data.setVideoNames(videoNames);
            Data.setVideoURLs(videoURLs);
            Data.setVideoDescriptions(videoDescriptions);

            if (this.dataReceivedCallback)
            {
                this.dataReceivedCallback();    /* Notify all data is received and stored */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why doesnt it accept my generated xml file?

Regards
M

Comment: No, your XML is being built totally invalid. You have `<channel>` inside your loop, but only close it OUTSIDE the loop. You also close `</item>` inside the loop, but never have a `<item>` to open that tag.

Comment: Yes you are right, i fixed that first channel in loop was meant to be opening item tag. But still result is the same:  TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this.XHRObj.responseXML.documentElement')

Comment: basic debugging then: check the raw response to see what came over from the server, before it goes into the xml parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, in php headers content type was wrong.

Changed 
`header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');`

to

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
```

Now it works perfect!

Comment: Can you show me how to load the xml to the player? How to modify the player gui ?I have downloaded the sample demo app and want to learn from it.